# What is the physical interpretation of a Godel sentence?

Tags: logic, physics

If I think of the laws of physics as a system of axioms then what is the physical interpretation of a Godel sentence? I'm trying to wrap my head around what Godel's theorem means for physics?

More specifically imagine I have a system of axioms which approximates reality then what does the Godel sentence mean for this system of axioms physically?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135560/discussion-on-question-by-more-anonymous-what-is-the-physical-interpretation-of).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2486348/21820) which gives not only a full proof of the generalized incompleteness theorem, but also an explicit independent sentence W'. This sentence asserts that some concrete program (which we can actually write down in not too many bytes if we are given any reasonable formal system T) does not halt, and W' is true if the system T is consistent. Note that this W' corresponds to Rosser's version, which is a stronger result than Godel's. (There is a similar one for Godel's sentence.)

So the Godel/Rosser sentence does have a concrete physical meaning; it implies that for any formal system T that we actually use for reasoning, there is a concrete program G and input I that we can write down (based on T) such that if T is consistent then:
(1) G does not halt on I.
(2a) T does not prove that G does not halt on I.
(2b) T does not prove that G halts on I.

Is this physically meaningful enough for you?

Comment: What would an example of G and  I be for an actual computer?

Comment: As stated in the linked post, T must have a proof verifier V, and the "can reason about programs" must be witnessed by a translation from those sentences about programs to sentences in T, so of course you need to provide both V and the translation before you can ask for G,I. Since it can clearly be done, there's not much reason to actually do it. Also, you should probably not talk about "actual computers", since they are not Turing-complete...

Comment: Talking about how something *can* be done isn't as useful as giving an actual real-world example when they're asking about a physical interpretation of a mathematical concept.

Comment: @nick012000: As I said, the linked post gives the sentence already. You just have to plug in the V and the translation for your formal system T. The program is literally given in that post, just in pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

The physical axioms of a physical theory or model can never be proven to have come about by using the axioms of the theory. That's why no theory or model of the universe can explain how the universe itself came about and are we obliged to turn to something different than physics to explain its existence. If the gaps are closed and a god of the gaps is no longer needed there is only one logical conclusion left. Gödel's incompleteness theorem directly leads to the existence of gods. Gödel's incompleteness can be completed by God only.

Answer (score 0):

This is not complicated. It simply says that there can never be a provably complete unified theory. But this is nothing new. Popper characterised a properly scientific theory as one that can be falsified.

Moreover, Goedels theorem on incompleteness is something of a red herring when it comes to philosophical discussion of truth and proof. It doesn't take an elaborate mathematical edifice to see that there are many things that are true but unproveable but simply a little philosophical maturity. That people appear to take it so is simply a modern secular manifestation of that occult discipline called numerology. Which just goes to show that old superstitions just don't go away but mutate, change and evolve with the times.

What Goedels theorem was good for was maths - not philosophy. It propelled the development of mathematical logic and model theory. But that should be no surprise, after all his theorem is just that - some maths.

Answer (score -1):

The Gödel sentence for our universe *just is* the Gödel sentence in our physical minds (for whichever mathematical logic our minds in this universe obey, as long as it is a logic that can yield such a sentence).

More pointedly, though, there is a "weak" but real relationship between incompleteness phenomena and the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem#G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems). Depending on if you reject physical [hypercomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation), you might frame a physical interpretation/interpolation of the Gödel sentence in terms of physically realizable computation states (for physical computers).

---

***A very late addition:*** I would recommend ["Epistemic Horizons and the Foundations of Quantum Mechanics"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.10668.pdf) for considerations regarding the relationship between formal incompleteness phenomena and epistemic limitations in connection with the axiomatization of quantum physics.

Comment: "The Gödel sentence for our universe just is the Gödel sentence in our physical minds" To construct a Gödel sentence for a physical world wouldn't you have to concentrate on some subset of physical activity that can be interpreted as "reliable theorem-proving in first-order arithmetic"? If the mathematical community produces a proof of some theorem which mathematicians continue to consider valid, but meanwhile some random person asserts the theorem is false, you wouldn't consider that as a demonstration that the universe is an "inconsistent system" in the Gödelian sense, would you?

Comment: I guess I would just be saying that the mental limitation imposed by the incompleteness phenomena, if it is also a physical limitation, embodies the unprovable sentence, if "provable" is taken cognitively (i.e. for a conscious process).

Comment: That doesn't even make any sense. There are no axioms of physics that satisfy the premises of Gödel's first incompleteness theorem. In fact there isn't any axiomitization of physics.

Comment: If an axiom is "just a belief," but if beliefs are physical (if physicalism is true, or something along that line), then a limit on axioms is a limit on beliefs in some way, and in turn a physical limit.